IAM Policy to pull an Image from ECR?
I'm searching AWS documentation but I'm still unclear on what ECR resource policy is necessary to retrieve an image from ECR?
The error I'm receiving is
CannotPullContainerError: The task cannot pull <image>. 
There is a connection issue between the task and the registry. 
Check your task network configuration. : 
failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: 
failed open: 
failed to do request: 
Get <image>: i/o timeout

Below is my IAM policy, which the role has assumed
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:<myArn>",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "batch:DescribeJobs",
                "batch:ListJobs",
                "batch:TerminateJob",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:PutImageTagMutability",
                "ecr:TagResource",
                "ecs:DescribeTasks",
                "ecs:RunTask",
                "ecs:StopTask",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
} 

Edit VPC construct below
import { DeploymentStackProps } from '@amzn/pipelines';

import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';

export interface VpcConstructProps extends DeploymentStackProps {
  stageName: string;
  modelContext: string;
  lambdaSourcePackage: string;
  lambdaImagePackage: string;
  fargateSourcePackage: string;
  fargateImagePackage: string;
  scheduleExpression: string;
}

export class VpcConstruct extends Construct {
  public readonly lambdaImageLocation: any;
  public readonly securityGroup: ec2.SecurityGroup;
  public readonly vpc: ec2.Vpc;
  public readonly ecrApiEndpoint: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint;
  public readonly ecrDkrEndpoint: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint;
  public readonly cloudwatchLogsEndpoint: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: VpcConstructProps) {
    super(scope, id);

    // Create VPC
    this.vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, `VPC-${props.modelContext}-${props.stageName}`, {
      maxAzs: 3, // Maximum number of Availability Zones to use
      natGateways: 1, // Number of NAT Gateways to use
      subnetConfiguration: [
        {
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
          name: `PublicSubnet-${props.modelContext}-${props.stageName}`,
        },
        {
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
          name: `PrivateSubnet-${props.modelContext}-${props.stageName}`,
        },
      ],
    });

    // Add VPC endpoint for ECR API
    this.ecrApiEndpoint = new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(
      this,
      `EcrApiEndpoint-${props.modelContext}-${props.stageName}`,
      {
        vpc: this.vpc,
        service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.ECR,
      },
    );
    // Add VPC endpoint for ECR Docker
    this.ecrDkrEndpoint = new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(
      this,
      `EcrDkrEndpoint-${props.modelContext}-${props.stageName}`,
      {
        vpc: this.vpc,
        service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.ECR_DOCKER,
      },
    );
    // Optionally, you can add VPC endpoint for CloudWatch Logs if you're logging in a private subnet
    this.cloudwatchLogsEndpoint = new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(
      this,
      `CloudwatchLogsEndpoint-${props.modelContext}-${props.stageName}`,
      {
        vpc: this.vpc,
        service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.CLOUDWATCH_LOGS,
      },
    );

    this.securityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, `SecurityGroup-${props.modelContext}-${props.stageName}`, {
      vpc: this.vpc,
      allowAllOutbound: true,
    });
  }
}



That's a network connection error you are getting, not an IAM permissions error. It doesn't appear to be getting to the point of checking your permissions.

@MarkB, understood- I edited and attached my VPC construct in CDK. Am I missing something obvious like an internet gateway?

You should check in the AWS console that the security group(s) associated with those Interface Endpoints allow inbound traffic from wherever you are trying to do an ECR image pull from (ECS? AWS Batch?). You should also check that the endpoints are attached to the same subnets that you are trying to do an ECR pull from.
